# Parsing a tweet to extract hashtags into an array

Tags: python, arrays

I am having a heck of a time taking the information in a tweet including hashtags, and pulling each hashtag into an array using Python.  I am embarrassed to even put what I have been trying thus far.

For example, "I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!"

This should pull the 3 hashtags into an array.

Comment: The type you're interested in is called "list". There is a thing actually named "array" in Python in the module of the same name, but it's seldom used.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A simple regex should do the job:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!"
>>> re.findall(r"#(\w+)", s)
['stackoverflow', 'people', 'helpful']
```

Note though, that as suggested in other answers, this may also find non-hashtags, such as a hash location in a URL:

```
>>> re.findall(r"#(\w+)", "http://example.org/#comments")
['comments']
```

So another simple solution would be the following (removes duplicates as a bonus):

```
>>> def extract_hash_tags(s):
...    return set(part[1:] for part in s.split() if part.startswith('#'))
...
>>> extract_hash_tags("#test http://example.org/#comments #test")
set(['test'])
```

Comment: Your simple solution picks up too many characters: if you've a comma after a hashtag, for example, it ends up being included in the hashtag.

Comment: you should add re.UNICODE to work with unicode hashtags

Comment: It not covers only numbers hashtag exception like '#123'. I use r'\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*'.

Comment: maybe useful: here is how to time these functions

import timeit

timeit.timeit(
timeit.timeit('re.findall(r"#(\w+)", s)', setup="import re; s='I love #strackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!'", number=10000)
timeit.timeit('extract_hash_tags(s)', setup="import re; s='I love #strackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!'; from __main__ import extract_hash_tags", number=10000)

On my machine the regexp is faster.

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit-examples

Comment: kind of my own naive approach, then googling about hashtags... #this-is-not-a-hashtag #nufsaid.

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> s="I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!"
>>> [i  for i in s.split() if i.startswith("#") ]
['#stackoverflow', '#people', '#helpful!']
```

Comment: I think this is better than using the accepted response regex. This way something like http://example.com/index.html#anchor_link is not marked as an hashtag.

Comment: How to do a similar question using pandas ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044375/select-specific-keywords-from-content

Answer (score 13):

The best **Twitter hashtag regular expression**:

```
import re
text = "#promovolt #1st # promovolt #123"
re.findall(r'\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*', text)

>>> ['#promovolt', '#1st']
```

[image]

Comment: #1st is not a valid hashtag, though?

Comment: Hi @benzkji, as you can see above, #1st is a valid Twitter hashtag. #123 is invalid Twitter hashtag.

Comment: indeed! I was looking at the first google result, and took it for granted... https://www.hashtags.org/platforms/twitter/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/ also, your solution is way shortest, and just works. upvoted!

Answer (score 8):

Suppose that you have to retrieve your `#Hashtags` from a sentence full of punctuation symbols. Let's say that `#stackoverflow #people` and `#helpful`are terminated with different symbols, you want to retrieve them from `text` but you may want to avoid repetitions:

```
>>> text = "I love #stackoverflow, because #people... are very #helpful! Are they really #helpful??? Yes #people in #stackoverflow are really really #helpful!!!"
```

if you try with `set([i for i in text.split() if i.startswith("#")])` alone, you will get:

```
>>> set(['#helpful???',
 '#people',
 '#stackoverflow,',
 '#stackoverflow',
 '#helpful!!!',
 '#helpful!',
 '#people...'])
```

which in my mind is redundant. Better solution using RE with module `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> set([re.sub(r"(\W+)$", "", j) for j in set([i for i in text.split() if i.startswith("#")])])
>>> set(['#people', '#helpful', '#stackoverflow'])
```

Now it's ok for me.

**EDIT: UNICODE `#Hashtags`**

Add the `re.UNICODE` flag if you want to delete punctuations, but still preserving letters with accents, apostrophes and other unicode-encoded stuff which may be important if the `#Hashtags` may be expected not to be only in english... maybe this is only an italian guy nightmare, maybe not! ;-)

For example:

```
>>> text = u"I love #stackoverflòw, because #peoplè... are very #helpfùl! Are they really #helpfùl??? Yes #peoplè in #stackoverflòw are really really #helpfùl!!!"
```

will be unicode-encoded as:

```
>>> u'I love #stackoverfl\xf2w, because #peopl\xe8... are very #helpf\xf9l! Are they really #helpf\xf9l??? Yes #peopl\xe8 in #stackoverfl\xf2w are really really #helpf\xf9l!!!'
```

and you can retrieve your (correctly encoded) `#Hashtags` in this way:

```
>>> set([re.sub(r"(\W+)$", "", j, flags = re.UNICODE) for j in set([i for i in text.split() if i.startswith("#")])])
>>> set([u'#stackoverfl\xf2w', u'#peopl\xe8', u'#helpf\xf9l'])
```

**EDITx2: UNICODE `#Hashtags` and control for `#` repetitions**

If you want to control for multiple repetitions of the `#` symbol, as in (forgive me if the `text` example has become almost unreadable):

```
>>> text = u"I love ###stackoverflòw, because ##################peoplè... are very ####helpfùl! Are they really ##helpfùl??? Yes ###peoplè in ######stackoverflòw are really really ######helpfùl!!!"
>>> u'I love ###stackoverfl\xf2w, because ##################peopl\xe8... are very ####helpf\xf9l! Are they really ##helpf\xf9l??? Yes ###peopl\xe8 in ######stackoverfl\xf2w are really really ######helpf\xf9l!!!'
```

then you should substitute these multiple occurrences with a unique `#`.
A possible solution is to introduce another nested implicit `set()` definition with the `sub()` function replacing occurrences of more-than-1 `#` with a single `#`:

```
>>> set([re.sub(r"#+", "#", k) for k in set([re.sub(r"(\W+)$", "", j, flags = re.UNICODE) for j in set([i for i in text.split() if i.startswith("#")])])])
>>> set([u'#stackoverfl\xf2w', u'#peopl\xe8', u'#helpf\xf9l'])
```

Comment: your solution looks like the most complete. but. dashes and special chars still remain in hash tags? so you will get `#hash,tag` and `#what-ever` as tags...? is there an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

AndiDogs answer will screw up with links and other stuff, you may want to filter them out first. After that use this code:

```
UTF_CHARS = ur'a-z0-9_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff'
TAG_EXP = ur'(^|[^0-9A-Z&/]+)(#|\uff03)([0-9A-Z_]*[A-Z_]+[%s]*)' % UTF_CHARS
TAG_REGEX = re.compile(TAG_EXP, re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

It may seem overkill but this has been converted from here http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-java.
It will handle like 99% of all hashtags in the same way that twitter handles them.

For more converted twitter regex check out this: http://github.com/BonsaiDen/Atarashii/blob/master/atarashii/usr/share/pyshared/atarashii/formatter.py

**EDIT:**
Check out: http://github.com/BonsaiDen/AtarashiiFormat

Comment: You can use (?:^|[^0-9A-Z&/]+)(?:#|\uff03)([0-9A-Z_]*[A-Z_]+[%s]*) to only extract the hashtag text itself, rather than a tuple with a space and the hashtag and text

Answer (score 3):

simple gist (better than chosen answer)
https://gist.github.com/mahmoud/237eb20108b5805aed5f
also work with unicode hashtags

Comment: yep, it's definitely better, because accepted answer extracts `test)` from `(#test)`, while this gist returns `test`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
hashtags = [word for word in tweet.split() if word[0] == "#"]
```

Comment: You mean `==`, not `=`. (Also, `word.startswith("#")` is preferred to `word[0] == "#"`.)

Answer (score 0):

i had a lot of issues with unicode languages.

i had seen many ways to extract hashtag, but found non of them answering on all cases

so i wrote some small python code to handle most of the cases. it works for me.

```
def get_hashtagslist(string):
    ret = []
    s=''
    hashtag = False
    for char in string:
        if char=='#':
            hashtag = True
            if s:
                ret.append(s)
                s=''           
            continue

        # take only the prefix of the hastag in case contain one of this chars (like on:  '#happy,but i..' it will takes only 'happy'  )
        if hashtag and char in [' ','.',',','(',')',':','{','}'] and s:
            ret.append(s)
            s=''
            hashtag=False 

        if hashtag:
            s+=char

    if s:
        ret.append(s)

    return list(set([word for word in ret if len(ret)>1 and len(ret)<20]))
```

Answer (score -2):

I extracted hashtags in a silly but effective way.

```
def retrive(s):
    indice_t = []
    tags = []
    tmp_str = ''
    s = s.strip()
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == "#":
            indice_t.append(i)
    for i in range(len(indice_t)):
        index = indice_t[i]
        if i == len(indice_t)-1:
            boundary = len(s)
        else:
            boundary = indice_t[i+1]
        index += 1
        while index < boundary:
            if s[index] in "`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|\\:;'"",.<>?/ \n\t":
                tags.append(tmp_str)
                tmp_str = ''
                break
            else:
                tmp_str += s[index]
                index += 1
        if tmp_str != '':
            tags.append(tmp_str)
    return tags
```

Comment: please remove junk comment