# Converting a python set into a XML element

Tags: python, lxml

I'm still new in making python apps... But I'm willing to learn...

I want to make hash tags (converted from a string that was generated) and turn them into an element for an XML etree.

e.g.

from the string (object `rawData`)

```
rawData = "I'm soooo sleepy - feeling bored #journal #asleep"
```

I already got code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527892/parsing-a-tweet-to-extract-hashtags-into-an-array-in-python) to convert these hashtags (`#journal` and `#asleep`) into a python set:

```
hashTags = extract_hash_tags(rawData)
```

Result would be this (Now I already have a set of tags):

```
hashTags = set(['journal', 'asleep'])
```

The problem now is to make that set into:

```
<array>
       <string>journal</string>
       <string>asleep</string>
</array>
```

I know that I'm gonna make a loop for this that'll make individual parts of the set into elements.

I'm still rusty at loops though.

I'm using lxml because I need to prettify the xml. It gets the job done though.

EDIT: The answer for the stackoverflow question used a set not an array. Sorry 'bout that mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lxml.

```
from lxml import etree

# Code to make hashTags list...

array = etree.Element('array')
# Note: array can be also SubElement(parent, 'array')
for hash in hashTags:
    string = etree.SubElement(array, 'string')
    string.text = hash
print(etree.tostring(array, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Okay then, I'll try that... Can I also use this for sets as well?

Comment: Sets are almost the same as lists, with assurance of uniqueness.

Comment: Well, I tried the code and it worked! It outputted quite well after I exported the strings to XML. Thanks for the code sir... And yup, it worked on sets as well as arrays.