# Parsing tweets stored in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, twitter

I'm trying to parse through tweets which are stored in a column called "text" in a .csv file. I want to use regex, TweetTokenizer, etc., but that all requires that the text be in string form (as far as I understand).

I saw this post:

[Parsing a tweet inside a csv column in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354067/parsing-a-tweet-inside-a-csv-column-in-python)

but for me, the code is too specific to finding hashtags. I do want to do that, but does anyone know how to more generally turn the text in that "text" column into strings so I can parse?

Thanks,
punpun

Comment: You should be able to extract the "text" column from the dataframe, save it as a list and parse the elements of the list. Unless I'm missing the point here.

Comment: @fulaphex do you know how to parse all the elements of the list at once? For example, running— 

re.findall(r"#(\w+)", tweetlist)

—returns TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. Basically I want to make one big string of all the tweets and be able to parse through that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34011944/11295826

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Text columns should be imported as strings when you read the csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            user                                               text
0  scotthamilton  is upset that he can't update his Facebook by ...
1       mattycus  @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Man...
2        ElleCTF     my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire
3         Karoli  @nationwideclass no, it's not behaving at all....
4       joy_wolf                       @Kwesidei not the whole crew
5        mybirch                                         Need a hug
```

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
user    object
text    object
dtype: object
```

The Pandas `object` dtype is the same as Python `str` type, and is used for text.

If you do need to convert the column type to str, you can use the following:

```
df.text = df.text.astype(str)
```