# Extracting hashtags from each string in a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas, data-cleaning

Python noob here. (full disclosure)

I've got a list of Tweets that is formatted as a list of strings, like so:

```
["This is a string that needs processing #ugh #yikes",
"this string doesn't have hashtags",
"this is another one #hooray"]
```

I'm trying to write a function that will create a list of the hashtags in each line but leave blank entries when there aren't any entries. This is because I want to join this list with the tweets themselves later. This is my desired output:

```
['#ugh', '#yikes'], [], ['#hooray']
```

This function which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527892/parsing-a-tweet-to-extract-hashtags-into-an-array-in-python) works fine for ONE string.

```
 mystring = "I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!"
```

But it doesn't seem to work for several strings. This is my code:

```
 l = len(mystringlist)
 it = iter(mystringlist)

 taglist = []

 def extract_tags(it,l):
      for item in mystringlist:
         output = list([re.sub(r"(\W+)$", "", j) for j in list([i for i in 
         item.split() if i.startswith("#")])])
    taglist.append(output)

 multioutput = extract_tags(mystringlist,l)

 print(multioutput)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be considered unreadable or overkill for the task at hand, but avoids using regular expressions and should therefore be somewhat faster:

```
>>> def hashtags(tweet):
....    return list(filter(lambda token: token.startswith('#'), tweet.split()))

>>> [hashtags(tweet) for tweet in tweets]
[['#ugh', '#yikes'], [], ['#hooray']]
```

Comment: `In [9]: %timeit [hashtags(tweet) for tweet in tweets]
6.72 µs ± 28.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: `In [10]: %timeit [re.findall('#\w+', i) for i in tweets]
3.4 µs ± 59.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: Is it possible to rework this so that it all operates inside of a def() function? (for modularity purposes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression and `re.findall`.

[`#\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/Xf8iGm/1) will match a hashtag followed by any word character, which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
x = ["This is a string that needs processing #ugh #yikes",
"this string doesn't have hashtags",
"this is another one #hooray"]

import re

hashtags = [re.findall('#\w+', i) for i in x]
print(hashtags)
```

Output:

```
[['#ugh', '#yikes'], [], ['#hooray']]
```

If the regular expression does *not* match anything, an empty list will be returned, as is expected in your desired output.

If there is the possibility of your text containing `urls`, something like `www.mysite.com/#/dashboard`, you could use:

[`[\s^](#\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Xf8iGm/3)

To ensure that the hashtag is found following whitespace or at the start of a line.